# syntax error, unexpected 'have' (T_STRING)

Tags: newsletter, php, mage

how to fix this **syntax error**,

> unexpected 'have' (T_STRING) in
>   /home/mithraa/public_html/svirtzone.com/projects/fandc/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php

```
public function unsubscribecusAction()
{
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam(’email’);
    $subsModel = Mage::getModel(’newsletter/subscriber’);
    $subscriber = $subsModel->loadByEmail($email);

    $id = (int) $subsModel->getId();
    $code = (string) $subsModel->getCode();
    if ($id && $code) {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton(’core/session’);
        try {
               Mage::getModel(’newsletter/subscriber’)->load($id)->setCheckCode($code)->unsubscribe();
               $session->addSuccess($this->__(’You have been unsubscribed.’));
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__(’There was a problem with the un-subscription.’));
        }
     }
     $this->_redirectReferer();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong quotation mark characters to declare strings:

**Correct:**

```
'hello', "hello"
```

**Wrong:**

```
’hello’
```

Answer (score 0):

Change (Quotation Marks) `’` to `'`

```
    public function unsubscribecusAction()
    {
      $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
      $subsModel = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
      $subscriber = $subsModel->loadByEmail($email);

      $id = (int) $subsModel->getId();
      $code = (string) $subsModel->getCode();
        if ($id && $code) {
       $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        try {
        Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load($id)->setCheckCode($code)->unsubscribe();
        $session->addSuccess($this->__('You have been unsubscribed.'));
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
              $session->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
        }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                 $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the un-subscription.'));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you using `tiled sign` sign instead of use single `'` OR `"` for everywhere in your code. like as

`’email’` replace with `'email'` OR `"email"`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the difference between the `’` and `'` character. See if this works;

```
public function unsubscribecusAction() {
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $subsModel = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber');
    $subscriber = $subsModel->loadByEmail($email);

    $id = (int) $subsModel->getId();
    $code = (string) $subsModel->getCode();
    if ($id && $code) {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        try {
            Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->load($id)->setCheckCode($code)->unsubscribe();
            $session->addSuccess($this->__('You have been unsubscribed.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the un-subscription.'));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```